# How to declare a global variable throughout a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I'm a newbie in python and I'm trying to write a program that connect to an Arduino through selected COM port and constantly updating the status (connected or disconnected)

I'm using a timer that update every 1 second. The problem here is every time I run the code, it says `Ser` in `Ontimer` is not defined even though I declared it previously in `on_press`. How can I fix this?

```py
class GuiFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,title):
        super().__init__(parent, title = title, size =(950,550))
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self, 1)
        self.timer.Start(100)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self.timer)

        st1 = wx.StaticText(panel, label='COM port: ', pos=(5, 5))

        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos=(5, 30))

        my_btn = wx.Button(panel, label='Enter', pos=(5, 65))
        my_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_press)

        self.sb = self.CreateStatusBar()

    def on_press(self,event):
        global Ser
        com = self.text_ctrl.GetValue()
        if not com:
            print("Please enter port!")
        else:
            Ser = SerialCom(com,115200)
            self.sb.SetStatusText(Ser.connect())
            time.sleep(1)

    def OnTimer(self, event):
        global Ser
        self.sb.SetStatusText(Ser.status())
```

Comment: Are you sure that `on_press` is even executed before `OnTimer`?

Comment: Oh wow I didn't even realise that. I tried again and after connecting the first time this error goes away. Now how can I make sure that `Ser` is always defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] how can I make sure that Ser is always defined?

Init the variable `Ser` in global namespace by `None`:

```py
Ser = None
```

Check for `Ser != None` before it is read:

```py
class GuiFrame(wx.Frame):

    def on_press(self,event):
        global Ser
        com = self.text_ctrl.GetValue()
        if not com:
            print("Please enter port!")
        else:
            Ser = SerialCom(com,115200)
            self.sb.SetStatusText(Ser.connect())
            time.sleep(1)

    def OnTimer(self, event):
        if Set != None:
            self.sb.SetStatusText(Ser.status())
```

Note, if the variable is only attempted to read, then the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt) is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my day.